# What does the term offset means when a dmp is generated

Tags: c++, windows

When a Windows application crashes and a dmp file is generated what does the term offset means  ? I know it has something to do with the dmp analysis, but I don't know exactly what.

Comment: [Offset (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_%28computer_science%29): *integer indicating the distance (displacement) from the beginning of the object up until a given element or point, presumably within the same object*.